# GUI objects disappearing when adding center panel to my content pane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, containers

I'm creating a simple UI using GUI objects to input data but whenever I add the center panel to the contentPane, my JLabels disappear.  Additionally, the JTextFields, JComboBoxs and JButtons don't respond to clicking or entering keystrokes.  If I don't add the centerPanel, or add it and start the applet with width and height parameters of 1 and 1, everything works perfectly.

When I stretch out the screen, after adding the center panel to a normal run configuration, the objects will appear outside of the initial window.  I've defined all of the objects as private instance variables before the listed code, so that isn't the issue.  Please help, I'm baffled!

Here's my code:

```
public void begin() {
    // creates the GUI Objects for the northPanel
    northPanel = new JPanel();
    northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));

    searchBox = new JTextField();
    searchBoxLabel = new JLabel("Search ID #:");
    search = new JButton("Search");
    search.addActionListener(this);

    northPanel.add(searchBoxLabel);
    northPanel.add(searchBox);
    northPanel.add(search);

    // creates the GUI OBjects for the southPanel
    southDivider = new JPanel();
    southDivider.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

    southPanel = new JPanel();
    southPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    enter = new JButton("Enter");
    incrementInfo = new JButton("Increment ID");
    setCurrentTimeDate = new JButton("Current Time/Date");
    findRate = new JButton("Find Yield Rate");

    findRate.addActionListener(this);
    enter.addActionListener(this);
    incrementInfo.addActionListener(this);
    setCurrentTimeDate.addActionListener(this);

    southPanel.add(findRate);
    southPanel.add(setCurrentTimeDate);
    southPanel.add(incrementInfo);
    southPanel.add(enter);

    messageLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to the Stringer Application");

    southDivider.add(southPanel);
    southDivider.add(messageLabel);

    // create the GUI objects on the eastPanel
    eastPanel = new JPanel();
    eastPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));

    cellType = new JComboBox();
    cellType.addItem("Rect");
    cellType.addItem("Cham");
    cellTypeLabel = new JLabel("Cell Type:");

    ecaCode = new JComboBox();
    ecaCode.addItem("A");
    ecaCode.addItem("B");
    ecaCodeLabel = new JLabel("ECA Code:");

    ecaSyringeNum = new JTextField();
    ecaSyringeNumLabel = new JLabel("Eca Syringe #:");

    passFail = new JComboBox();
    passFail.addItem("Pass");
    passFail.addItem("Fail");
    passFailLabel = new JLabel("Pass/Fail:");

    operator = new JTextField();
    operatorLabel = new JLabel("Operator:");
    cellType.addActionListener(this);
    ecaCode.addActionListener(this);
    passFail.addActionListener(this);

    eastPanel.add(operatorLabel);
    eastPanel.add(operator);
    eastPanel.add(cellTypeLabel);
    eastPanel.add(cellType);
    eastPanel.add(ecaCodeLabel);
    eastPanel.add(ecaCode);
    eastPanel.add(ecaSyringeNumLabel);
    eastPanel.add(ecaSyringeNum);
    eastPanel.add(passFailLabel);
    eastPanel.add(passFail);

    // create the GUI objects on the westPanel
    westPanel = new JPanel();
    westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));

    yieldLabel = new JLabel("Current Yield:");
    yieldValueLabel = new JLabel("Select Date/Times");
    yieldAfterDate = new JTextField();
    yieldAfterTime = new JTextField();
    yieldBeforeDate = new JTextField();
    yieldBeforeTime = new JTextField();
    yieldAfterDateLabel = new JLabel("After Date:");
    yieldAfterTimeLabel = new JLabel("After Time:");
    yieldBeforeDateLabel = new JLabel("Before Date:");
    yieldBeforeTimeLabel = new JLabel("Before Time:");
    setBeforeToCurrentLabel = new JLabel("<html>'Set to Current' for <br> Current Date/Time</html>");
    fillBeforeWithCurrent = new JButton("Set to Current");
    fillBeforeWithCurrent.addActionListener(this);

    westPanel.add(yieldLabel);
    westPanel.add(yieldValueLabel);
    westPanel.add(yieldAfterDateLabel);
    westPanel.add(yieldAfterDate);
    westPanel.add(yieldAfterTimeLabel);
    westPanel.add(yieldAfterTime);
    westPanel.add(yieldBeforeDateLabel);
    westPanel.add(yieldBeforeDate);
    westPanel.add(yieldBeforeTimeLabel);
    westPanel.add(yieldBeforeTime);
    westPanel.add(setBeforeToCurrentLabel);
    westPanel.add(fillBeforeWithCurrent);

    // create the GUI objects for the centerPanel
    centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));


    date = new JTextField(getCurrentDate());
    dateLabel = new JLabel("Date:");
    time = new JTextField(getCurrentTime());
    timeLabel = new JLabel("Time:");
    stringID = new JTextField();
    stringIDLabel = new JLabel("String ID:");
    cellLot = new JTextField();
    cellLotLabel = new JLabel("Cell Lot #:");
    cellEff = new JTextField();
    cellEffLabel = new JLabel("Cell Eff:");
    comments = new JTextField();
    commentsLabel = new JLabel("Comments:");

    centerPanel.add(dateLabel);
    centerPanel.add(date);
    centerPanel.add(timeLabel);
    centerPanel.add(time);
    centerPanel.add(stringIDLabel);
    centerPanel.add(stringID);
    centerPanel.add(cellLotLabel);
    centerPanel.add(cellLot);
    centerPanel.add(cellEffLabel);
    centerPanel.add(cellEff);
    centerPanel.add(commentsLabel);
    centerPanel.add(comments);


    // add the panel's to the contentPane
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(southDivider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    contentPane.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    contentPane.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    contentPane.validate();

}
```

Comment: You've posted a code snippet that's intriguing, but it's not code that we can compile, run, test, modify or correct. Please create and post a valid [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and it is working with no problems.
Most likely you are adding components some where else to the container, and by default any added components goes to center, which cause the old center panel to be removed , and the the swing frame to draw dirty area.[image]

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test2 extends JFrame {
    public Test2() {
        begin();
    }
    public void begin() {
        // creates the GUI Objects for the northPanel
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));

        JTextField searchBox = new JTextField();
        JLabel searchBoxLabel = new JLabel("Search ID #:");
        JButton search = new JButton("Search");

        northPanel.add(searchBoxLabel);
        northPanel.add(searchBox);
        northPanel.add(search);

        // creates the GUI OBjects for the southPanel
        JPanel southDivider = new JPanel();
        southDivider.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        JButton incrementInfo = new JButton("Increment ID");
        JButton setCurrentTimeDate = new JButton("Current Time/Date");
        JButton findRate = new JButton("Find Yield Rate");

        southPanel.add(findRate);
        southPanel.add(setCurrentTimeDate);
        southPanel.add(incrementInfo);
        southPanel.add(enter);

        JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to the Stringer Application");

        southDivider.add(southPanel);
        southDivider.add(messageLabel);

        // create the GUI objects on the eastPanel
        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));

        JComboBox cellType = new JComboBox();
        cellType.addItem("Rect");
        cellType.addItem("Cham");
        JLabel cellTypeLabel = new JLabel("Cell Type:");

        JComboBox ecaCode = new JComboBox();
        ecaCode.addItem("A");
        ecaCode.addItem("B");
        JLabel ecaCodeLabel = new JLabel("ECA Code:");

        JTextField ecaSyringeNum = new JTextField();
        JLabel ecaSyringeNumLabel = new JLabel("Eca Syringe #:");

        JComboBox passFail = new JComboBox();
        passFail.addItem("Pass");
        passFail.addItem("Fail");
        JLabel passFailLabel = new JLabel("Pass/Fail:");

        JTextField operator = new JTextField();
        JLabel operatorLabel = new JLabel("Operator:");

        eastPanel.add(operatorLabel);
        eastPanel.add(operator);
        eastPanel.add(cellTypeLabel);
        eastPanel.add(cellType);
        eastPanel.add(ecaCodeLabel);
        eastPanel.add(ecaCode);
        eastPanel.add(ecaSyringeNumLabel);
        eastPanel.add(ecaSyringeNum);
        eastPanel.add(passFailLabel);
        eastPanel.add(passFail);

        // create the GUI objects on the westPanel
        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));

        JLabel yieldLabel = new JLabel("Current Yield:");
        JLabel yieldValueLabel = new JLabel("Select Date/Times");
        JTextField yieldAfterDate = new JTextField();
        JTextField yieldAfterTime = new JTextField();
        JTextField yieldBeforeDate = new JTextField();
        JTextField yieldBeforeTime = new JTextField();
        JLabel yieldAfterDateLabel = new JLabel("After Date:");
        JLabel yieldAfterTimeLabel = new JLabel("After Time:");
        JLabel yieldBeforeDateLabel = new JLabel("Before Date:");
        JLabel yieldBeforeTimeLabel = new JLabel("Before Time:");
        JLabel setBeforeToCurrentLabel = new JLabel("<html>'Set to Current' for <br> Current Date/Time</html>");
        JButton fillBeforeWithCurrent = new JButton("Set to Current");

        westPanel.add(yieldLabel);
        westPanel.add(yieldValueLabel);
        westPanel.add(yieldAfterDateLabel);
        westPanel.add(yieldAfterDate);
        westPanel.add(yieldAfterTimeLabel);
        westPanel.add(yieldAfterTime);
        westPanel.add(yieldBeforeDateLabel);
        westPanel.add(yieldBeforeDate);
        westPanel.add(yieldBeforeTimeLabel);
        westPanel.add(yieldBeforeTime);
        westPanel.add(setBeforeToCurrentLabel);
        westPanel.add(fillBeforeWithCurrent);

        // create the GUI objects for the centerPanel
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));

        JTextField date = new JTextField();
        JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel("Date:");
        JTextField time = new JTextField();
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel("Time:");
        JTextField stringID = new JTextField();
        JLabel stringIDLabel = new JLabel("String ID:");
        JTextField cellLot = new JTextField();
        JLabel cellLotLabel = new JLabel("Cell Lot #:");
        JTextField cellEff = new JTextField();
        JLabel cellEffLabel = new JLabel("Cell Eff:");
        JTextField comments = new JTextField();
        JLabel commentsLabel = new JLabel("Comments:");

        centerPanel.add(dateLabel);
        centerPanel.add(date);
        centerPanel.add(timeLabel);
        centerPanel.add(time);
        centerPanel.add(stringIDLabel);
        centerPanel.add(stringID);
        centerPanel.add(cellLotLabel);
        centerPanel.add(cellLot);
        centerPanel.add(cellEffLabel);
        centerPanel.add(cellEff);
        centerPanel.add(commentsLabel);
        centerPanel.add(comments);

        // add the panel's to the contentPane
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(southDivider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPane.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        contentPane.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

//      contentPane.validate();
        setSize(812, 514);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 t=new Test2();

//      t.begin();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jalal!  I checked but that's not the case with my code, I only add components inside the above begin method.  I wonder why it's not working on mine :/  Would you mind posting your full code of what you put into your compiler  (including class signature, imports, ect)  to see if that may allow some clarity?

Comment: Most you are most welcome!
Kindly accept the answer if you consider it solved.